# Primefaces File download proper exception handling

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with the download p:CommandButton:

- If I set Ajax=false, and there's a problem during the download:
  the whole page refreshes, which causes undesired behavior from the application as I have dialogues with flags to show or hide.
  I handled that by downloading nothing!!

xhtml Code:

```
<p:commandButton   id="downloadExcelFile" rendered="#{!login.connectedUserHasRole('Client')}"  value="Exporter"  actionListener="#{etudeManagedBean.exportChartBilan}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s" >
        <p:fileDownload value="#{etudeManagedBean.bilanFile}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
```

ManagedBean's code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "etudeManagedBean")
@ViewScoped
public class EtudeManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(EtudeManagedBean.class);
    @ManagedProperty("#{login}")
    private Login login;
    @EJB
    private EtudeFacadeLocal etudeFacade;
    @EJB
    private PreRequisFacadeLocal preRequisFacade;
    @EJB
    private UtilisateurFacadeLocal utilisateurFacade;
    @EJB
    private Utilisateur selectedUtilisateur;
    private EtudeModel etudeModel;
    private StreamedContent bilanFile;
    private StreamedContent templateFile;
    private List<String> selectedJalonList;
    private boolean skip, requestFromCbCs;
    private List<Cb> listCb, listCbByEtude;
    private List<PreRequis> listPreRequisByEtude;
    private List<BilanLivraisonDto> listSemaineLivFinal;
    private PieChartModel pieModel;
    private PieChartModel pieModelBilanLiv;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        etudeForFiltering = new Etude();
        selectedEtude = new Etude();
        initialisationUser();
        recherche();
        findListBilanLivraisonDto();
        createPieModel();
        createPieModelBIlanLiv();
    }


    public void exportChartBilan() {
        try {
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat formater = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
            String exportBilanDate = formater.format(date);
            String nameBilanFile = "Bilan_" + exportBilanDate + ".xlsx";
            FileInputStream chart_file_input = null;
            if (!listSemaineLivFinal.isEmpty()) {
                String listePath = "/pages/generatedFiles/BilanExport.xlsx";
                String listePathCopie = "/pages/generatedFiles/BilanExportCopie.xlsx";
                String tempBilanFileRealPath = fc.getExternalContext().getRealPath(listePath);
                String tempCopieBilanFileRealPath = fc.getExternalContext().getRealPath(listePathCopie);
                InputStream inputXlsFile = null;
                ExcelFileHelper helper = new ExcelFileHelper();
                helper.deleteAndCreateExcelFile(tempCopieBilanFileRealPath, tempBilanFileRealPath);
                String tempFilePath = fc.getExternalContext().getRealPath(listePath);
                System.out.println("tempFilePath: " + tempFilePath);
                inputXlsFile = fc.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(listePath);
                chart_file_input = new FileInputStream(new File(tempFilePath));
                XSSFWorkbook my_workbook = null;
                my_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(chart_file_input);
                XSSFSheet my_sheet = my_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                // helper.clearContentCell(tempFilePath);
                inputXlsFile = fc.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(listePath);
                List<BilanLivraisonDto> etudeList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (BilanLivraisonDto etude : listSemaineLivFinal) {
                    etudeList.add(etude);
                }
                List<String> totalList = new ArrayList();
                totalList.add(String.valueOf(getTotaleNbreLivTotale()));
                totalList.add(String.valueOf(getTotaleNbreLivPartiel()));
                totalList.add(String.valueOf(getTotaleNbreLivOptim()));
                totalList.add(String.valueOf(getTotaleNbreLivPDHPDH()));
                totalList.add(String.valueOf(getTotaleNbreLivPDHSDH()));
                totalList.add(String.valueOf(getTotaleNbreLivSDHSDH()));
                List<String> percentageList = new ArrayList();
                percentageList.add(String.format("%.2f", getPourcentageForNbreLivTotale() * 100));
                percentageList.add(String.format("%.2f", getPourcentageForNbreLivPartiel() * 100));
                percentageList.add(String.format(" %.2f", getPourcentageForNbreLivOptim() * 100));
                percentageList.add(String.format(" %.2f", getPourcentageForNbreLivPDHPDH() * 100));
                percentageList.add(String.format("%.2f", getPourcentageForNbreLivPDHSDH() * 100));
                percentageList.add(String.format(" %.2f", getPourcentageForNbreLivSDHSDH() * 100));
                helper.editGeneratedExcelFoBilan(my_workbook, etudeList, totalList, percentageList);
                /* Create JFreeChart object that will hold the Pie Chart Data */
                DefaultPieDataset my_pie_chart_data = new DefaultPieDataset();
                DefaultPieDataset my_pie_chart_data_liv = new DefaultPieDataset();
                my_pie_chart_data.setValue("SDH-SDH", getPourcentageForNbreLivSDHSDH() * 100);
                my_pie_chart_data.setValue("PDH-SDH", getPourcentageForNbreLivPDHSDH() * 100);
                my_pie_chart_data.setValue("PDH-PDH", getPourcentageForNbreLivPDHPDH() * 100);
                my_pie_chart_data.setValue("Optim", getPourcentageForNbreLivOptim() * 100);
                my_pie_chart_data_liv.setValue("Livraison totale", getPourcentageForNbreLivTotale() * 100);
                my_pie_chart_data_liv.setValue("Livraison partielle", getPourcentageForNbreLivPartiel() * 100);

                final JFreeChart myPieChartLiv;
                final JFreeChart myPieChartTypeConn;
                myPieChartLiv = createChart(my_pie_chart_data_liv, "Bilan livraison");
                myPieChartTypeConn = createChart(my_pie_chart_data, "Livraison par typologie");
                int width = 320; /* Width of the chart */
                int height = 300; /* Height of the chart */
                float quality = 1; /* Quality factor */
                ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream chart_out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(chart_out, quality, myPieChartTypeConn, width, height);
                ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(chart_out2, quality, myPieChartLiv, width, height);
                int my_picture_id = my_workbook.addPicture(chart_out.toByteArray(), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
                chart_out.close();
                chart_file_input.close();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(tempFilePath));
                my_workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                this.bilanFile = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(tempFilePath), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", nameBilanFile);
                System.out.println("le bilan est " + this.bilanFile);

                if (this.bilanFile == null) {
                    JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Le fichier indisponible");
                }

                JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("La génération du fichier est effectué avec succès.");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EtudeManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Le fichier indisponible");
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return the bilanFile
     */
    public StreamedContent getBilanFile() {
        return bilanFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param bilanFile the bilanFile to set
     */
    public void setBilanFile(StreamedContent bilanFile) {
        this.bilanFile = bilanFile;
    }

}
```

But in this case, I can't display an error on the page.

- If I set Ajax=true, the download won't start!

Comment: *"If I set Ajax=true, the download won't start"* It's impossible anyway to download files using ajax. This is a JavaScript security limitation, not a JSF one.

Answer (score 0):

According to primefaces doc when you use `<p:fileDownlaod .../>` inside `<p:commandButton>` or `<p:commandLink>` the attribute `ajax="false"` is required because the fileDownload requires full page refresh.You can look for other options like `<p:dataExporter>` or more advanced `<pe:exporter>`. You can also customize your excel file as your need.

Comment: The file i want to download  contain a chart and  tables that's why i proceed with file download not by dataExpoter

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you whole code. You can use rendered attribute in the dialogues and in your method exportChartBilan() set the flag to false. If there are other problems because of page refresh then look for other solutions.